# Use a common file to import ExtJS lib

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect to make a few web apps. After each build I am presented with an 'app.js' among other files. The 'app.js' of each build has 90% of its content in common with another app.

Is there a way to extract that information and leave it in a common directory on the app server to then be imported dynamically?

1. This would allow this large file to be cached by the server and browsers.
2. The load time of each app will decrease.
3. I will use less space on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... however this is far easier to accomplish without Sencha Architect.

Sencha Cmd has long had the concept of [packages](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html), and these are exactly the sort of thing you're asking for.

Sencha Architect does have the concepts of [app templates](https://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/extending_architect/creating_app_templates.html) as well as [extensions](https://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/reference/user_extension_structure.html) -- but they don't really give you the single cached JS file that you're looking for.

Sencha Cmd also has some deep utilities for manually compiling a shared resource, but honestly the "package" is ultimately what you'd want. Sadly I don't know how compatible they are with Architect.

Comment: Is this doable via Sencha command, I don't mind doing the builds on the command line if you could point me to how to do them

Comment: It's all located at docs.sencha.com, though without diving deeply into your code I don't know specifically where to point you. The link to "packages" should answer the majority of your questions, but the [compiler](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_compiler_reference.html) might also be helpful.